# How to refrence scripthookvdotnet in my c# .net framework

Tags: c#, scripting

Im brand new to the .netframework and using scripthookvdotnet, and all i can see is refrencing the .dll inside of scripthookvdotnet. But as off the new release there is no dll file or asi file that i can reference. How do i now reference scripthookvdotnet. Here is the template im trying to get to work:

```
using GTA;
using GTA.Native;
using GTA.Math;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyScript
{
    public class MyScript : Script
    {
        public MyScript()
        {
            // Subscribe to events here
            Tick += OnTick;
            KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
        }

        private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do something every game tick here
        }

        private void OnKeyDown(object sender, GTA.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do something when a key is pressed here
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried looking for the dll file, and the asi file; but i have had no luck.

all i need is the 'using gta.example' references to work.

Answer (score 0):

I download ScriptHookVDotNet v3.5.1 from github and the .dll and .asi files are there.

After downloading those files you will need to add a reference to the ScriptHookVdotNet.dll assembly. You can do this by right-clicking on the "References" folder in your project in the Solution Explorer, and selecting "Add Reference". Navigate to the folder where you have the ScriptHookVdotNet.dll and select it.

After that you can include the namespace in your code.

```
using ScriptHookVdotNet;
```